# Chrome eventually close - React JS

Tags: javascript, reactjs, google-chrome, web, dropzone.js

I have a web site developed using React JS for Navigators, on my computer is working ok, but in a tablet I have an issue. I implemented a simple file chooser filering images only. The problem happens when I took the photo using the camera, it is the camera app in the device, but it doesn't always return to my web site the photo, sometimes there navigator is closed or sometimes a message appears that say the memory is not enough to complete the task.

The problem occurs around once per every ten photos taken, it sounds like a memory leak.

I am using the DropzoneComponent in React to load the image, here is my code:

Component:

```
import DropzoneComponent from 'react-dropzone-component';
```

Cod:

```
<DropzoneComponent
    config={componentConfig}
    eventHandlers={eventHandlers}
    djsConfig={djsConfig}
/>
```

The configuration:

```
const djsConfig = {
   addRemoveLinks: true,
   autoProcessQueue: false,
   maxFiles: 1,
   maxFilesize: 1,
   acceptedFiles: "image/png,image/jpeg",
   dictDefaultMessage: 'Drop here the image or select',
   dictFileTooBig: 'File is too big',
   dictInvalidFileType: 'Invalid file',
};

const componentConfig = {
   iconFiletypes: ['.jpg', '.png'],
   showFiletypeIcon: true,
   postUrl: 'no-url'
};
```

When the image is loaded I do this things to process the image, but this method is not called.

```
  addedfile = (file) => {
      alert('OLA K ASE')
      this.dropzone.removeAllFiles();
      Resizer.imageFileResizer(
          file, //is the file of the new image that can now be uploaded...
          900, // is the maxWidth of the  new image
          900, // is the maxHeight of the  new image
          'JPEG', // is the compressFormat of the  new image
          92, // is the quality of the  new image
          0, // is the rotatoion of the  new image
          uri => {
             this.setState({ src: uri });
          },  // is the callBack function of the new image URI
          'base64'  // is the output type of the new image
      );
  }
```

Comment: To help you, you need to share your code, please do it